# background-size shifts image

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-size

I'm using skrollr to create a zoom effect, very similar to [this](http://www.squarespace.com/seven/mobileapps).

The background image I'm using is an SVG and the zoom effect is applied by changing the background-size from a very high value (>2500%) to 100%. Now, everything is working fine expect that it seems that the css property "background-size" is limited. I cannot apply values higher than ~2600%. If I do so, depending on the browser, the background-image will be shifted or won't be displayed at all.

The problem that occurs is that, for a fixed value (e.g. 2500%), depending on the screen size & resolution that a user has, the image might not be displayed properly (or not at all, as stated above). Is there a way to calculate, depending on the screen size & resolution, what the highest possible background-size is, such that the image will be displayed properly?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrem7kpt/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.bg-1 {
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url('http://imgh.us/world-map_sw-r.svg');
    background-size:3000% auto; /* change this to something (really) big, e.g. 7000 */
    background-position-y:43.55%; /* this number is specific to the svg */
    background-position-x:52.5%; /* this numbers is specific to the svg */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="content bg-1">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle? Also, what browser and version are you using?

Comment: i added a JSFiddle to the question together with the "core-code". it seems that the issue is specific to svg-images. I'm using Google Chrome (v47.0.2526.111) and Safari (v8.0.7 (10600.7.12))

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `px` instead of using `%` because, `%` have it's maximum value of `100`

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Naman00/5hu2u4sn/).